# pyQt5 handling multiple windows

Tags: pyqt5

A simple issue which I can't fix as I'm pretty newbie in using pyQt...
I have an application which has a window with a QPushButton1 and when it's clicked it opens up a second window with another QPushButton2. What is happening is when I close the second window pressing 'x' and I come back to the first one, if I click again the QPushButton1 the second window does not open. Only when I click one more the QPushButton1 the second window is opened. Maybe I would need to set self.w(second window) = None when the second window close, but I don't know where to put it. Thanks for any help

```
class MainWindow(QWidget, Ui_f_tabella):

def __init__(self):
    super().__init__()
    
    self.setupUi(self)
    self.w = None # No external window yet.
    self.pb_Ins.clicked.connect(self.inserimento_mat)
   
def inserimento_mat(self):

  if self.w is None:    
     self.w = InserimentoMateriali()
     self.w.show()
     self.w.pb_conf.clicked.connect(self.conferma_inserimento_materiali)  
  else:
     self.w.close()
     self.w = None # Discard reference, close window.

def conferma_inserimento_materiali(self):
   """Aggiunta nuova risorsa"""   

   self.data = []
   for field in (self.w.lE_descMat, self.w.dSB_pesoSp):    
        
        if not field.text():
            QMessageBox.critical(
                self,
                "Errore!",
                f"Inserimento non consentito per mancanza di informazioni"   
                #f"Inserire il valore {field.objectName()}",
            )
            self.data = None  # Reset .data
            return

        self.data.append(field.text())

   if not self.data:
        return

   rec = self.model.record()
   rows = self.model.rowCount()

   for column_index, field in enumerate(self.data): 
      if rec.fieldName(column_index)=="ps_mat":
         x = field.replace(",", ".")
         field=x

      rec.setValue(rec.fieldName(column_index), field)     

   if(self.model.insertRecord(-1, rec)):
     self.model.submitAll() 
     self.model.select()
     QMessageBox.information(self, "Conferma inserimento",
                f"Inserimento nuovo materiale effettuato") 
     self.w.close()
     self.w = None           
   else:
     msg="Errore inserimento nuovo materiale: <br> <br>" + self.model.lastError().text()
     QMessageBox.critical(self, "ERRORE", msg)

class InserimentoMateriali(QDialog,Ui_InsMateriali):
    def __init__(self):
    super().__init__()
    self.setupUi(self)           

app = QApplication(sys.argv)
window = MainWindow()
window.show()
sys.exit(app.exec_())enter code here
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that when closing the window using the system buttons doesn't reset your `self.w`, so the `if self.w is None` condition is not met.

A possible solution is to set the `DeleteOnClose` attribute and connect the [`destroyed`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qobject.html#destroyed) signal to a function that restores the variable.

```
def inserimento_mat(self):

  if self.w is None:    
     self.w = InserimentoMateriali()
     self.w.setAttribute(Qt.WA_DeleteOnClose)
     self.w.destroyed.connect(self.resetFlag)
     self.w.show()
     self.w.pb_conf.clicked.connect(self.conferma_inserimento_materiali)  
  else:
     self.w.close()

def resetFlag(self):
  self.w = None
```

Comment: With your solution the application works as expected. Thanks a lot